# Unable to set text color of text view in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I am sorry to ask this silly question but I am unable to set textcolor property in android xml. 
This is my code:

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

and color :

```
 <color name="TextColor">#00427E</color>
```

I am able to see this color change in preview screens but not in real device.
 My .gradle includes:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Please help

Comment: which text color are you getting?

Comment: it should be work, please check same TextView at run time some where going to change

Comment: Change the `name="textColor"` and check.

Comment: chane TextColor to textcolor in your color.xml and add into your xml file   android:textColor="@color/textcolor"

Comment: @Hello World I am getting by default android text color

Comment: I changed to textColor but still no change in color

Comment: Moreover, I am taking this hash code directly in my text view, then also it doesnot change

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas see my answer below.

Comment: I have checked your `TextView Code`  with same `name="TextColor"` it is working perfect Ms. @PriyankaMinhas

Comment: But I am getting the issue.

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas Try to `Clean -> Rebuild` your Project or Restart `Android Studio`.

Comment: check it in some other device too.

Comment: Instead of setting through XML, have you try it programmatically?

Comment: @SundeepBadhotiya it works :) i dont know why not it works in xml , but it works programmatically Thank you

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas Also check with different device for case with `XML` only.

Comment: @Jaydroider yes sure

Comment: just try android:textColor="#00427E"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Programmatic Way

```
setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00427E"));
```

Or

```
setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TextColor);
```

Comment: where is your `color` location ?

Comment: `res/values/color.xml`

Answer (score 1):

### Try Textview xml code

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#00427E"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

IF don't Work this code use This Java side

```
setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00427E"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it happen may be if your Android Studio have lot of cache. so try to clean cache.

go to `File > invalidate Caches / Restart` click on it. may be solve your problem.

Comment: @Priyanka Minhas did you check it my answer.?

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. I think it is device specific problem. I tested in nexus,and motorola devices its working fine but pick a device default color in MI devices. To resolve this issue set the text color programaticly.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.TextColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

from what you have written, the implementation should work:

```
android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
```

is the attribute which changes the color of the text.

What i would suggest is, check the background color of the layout in which this TextView is placed. It is possible that the background color is the same as the color you are trying to set on the TextView, that is why you are not able to see the difference.

If you want to be double sure, set a black or white color on the TextView and see if it appears on as desired on screen.

If you still do not get the desired result, paste the full xml here so that we have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: thankyou for answering. I resolved it by setting the text color programmatically. I don't know, in xml, the desired color is not displaying at the run time. Although I can see those colors in the layouts as well. I checked by adding white and black colors But no use

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas, i know you must be fed up by now by this thing already, and since u already resolved it by code, you perhaps don't want to change anything now. But, just please give this last thing a try, if possible, instead of <color name="TextColor">#00427E</color> use <color name="textColor">#00427E</color> in your color.xml. I failed to notice this, and this may be the case. Instead of the capital T, use a smaller t. Kindly try it once, and let us know what happened.